# Search engine traffic as a site statistic on StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com

Area51 states that the ultimate goal for a StackExchange site is to have 90% of its traffic coming from search engines.  On the other hand, this statistic is visible only to moderators.   Why not make it publicly available as one of the sites' statistics featured on the [StackExchange.com sites tab](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true)?

Comment: What statistics would be useful?  And why?

Comment: @jdz I tried to clear it up.

Comment: I understand now, sounds like a good idea