# Consecutive edit suggestions should only reward rep once

Tags: feature-request, reputation, suggested-edits

I've made an edit suggestion to rephrase a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79173/search-engine-traffic-as-a-site-statistic-on-stackexchange-com) to be easier to read which was accepted.  I noticed however that in doing so, I made some grammatical errors in the change and offered another edit suggestion ASAP.  I was hoping to get that edit to come in before the 5 minute grace period but didn't get approved until after and counted as a separate edit.  I received rep for both.

While I welcome rep wherever I can get it, I think consecutive edit suggestions from a single person should only be rewarded once.  Chances are, all following suggestions are to fine tune the change that was previously made or to fix/add something that was overlooked.  If another user gets an edit between them, then any following suggestion could be rewarded.  Or maybe only once per question?

Do you agree?

Comment: This happened to me yesterday on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that the newer edit doesn't *replace* the previous edit entirely. Seems like an obvious way to save reviewer time and prevent rep gaming. It's not that uncommon to notice one last problem after you save an edit.

What I think it should do when you make a consecutive edit:

- If it has been accepted:

  - Remove any rep earned from previous edit
- If it's still pending review:

  - Remove previous edit from queue
  - Return accept/reject vote to any reviewers that judged the previous edit
  - add the new suggestion to the queue as if was the first one from that user

Comment: I agree. When I make a mistake in my edit (in my case I missed a critical typo IN THE TITLE), I should not be rewarded by getting double rep when I go back to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Mixed feelings here.

On the one hand, this tallies with the way `Copy Editor` and `Strunk & White` works, if I believe correctly, so I'd vote to keep it.

On the other hand, it can be abused.

Yet it cannot really be too bad because you max out at 500 edits, so whether you find another post to edit or use the same one.. really doesn't matter.  You may get red flagged though if you abuse it enough.

Comment: I don't see how this could even affect those badges.  I'm only concerned about the reputation that is awarded every time an edit suggestion is approved, not how many suggestions are made.

Comment: @Jeff - I think these count towards the badges too. And regardless of suggested/direct-edit (2k+ users), for **consistency** if you can edit a post 3 times and get 3 counts, then it makes sense to award the rep 3 times for suggested edits as well. And I _was_ in fact referring to approved edits, which is where the max=500 comes in (for max 1000 rep)