# Did the amount of reputation you get for editing questions change?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, suggested-edits

I noticed that I got 4 reputation for editing someones question. 2 after editing and 2 after someone approved the editing.

Is this a change that is made, or is it a bug ?

the following is shown in my overview:

```
 +4     1 hour ago  2 votes      Limiting the number of checkboxes selected by user
 +2     10:43   edit 
 +2     10:02   edit
```

And a link to the question's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6225592/revisions).

It "says" 2 "votes". Looks a bit strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made two separate edits.  One that edited the body of the post, and another later one that added a tag.  They are currently counted as two separate edits and you received reputation for both approvals.  I've put in a request to make [consecutive edits reward rep once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79588/consecutive-edit-suggestions-should-only-reward-rep-once).

Though it *is* odd that you received reputation for retagging when you have the rep for it already.  There have been [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/retagging-through-suggested-edits) to correct that that haven't been acted upon yet.  Though technically since you clicked on `edit`, it counted as an edit even if you did just a retag.

Not really bugs, just currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).